# Filtering rows in Pandas dataframe (preserving row indeces)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe named group containing only 0,1 values. I select only some columns from this dataframe:

```
cols = group.iloc[:,a:b+1]
```

Then, I sum rows of this new dataframe:

```
sums = pd.DataFrame(cols.sum(axis=1))
```

and select only those rows that have ratio of 1's in (lowerInterval, upperInterval)

```
selected = sums.loc[(sums.iloc[:,0]/(b-a+1) >= lowerInterval) & (sums.iloc[:,0]/(b-a+1) <= upperInterval)]
```

Now I want to get the rows from the group dataframe that satisfied conditions above like this:

```
return group.iloc[selected.index.values]
```

This works in most of the cases fine, however in some small percentage of cases the last line throws out of bound error, so I guess the row indeces are not preserved during these operations as I would expect.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: can you provide example data?, and where it works,and where it does not

Comment: The dataframes are quite big (10 thousand rows and 50 thousand columns) and since only small percentage of cases threw error, I don't know how to simulate the error on a small dataframe. However, @jezrael solution works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
return group.loc[selected.index]
```

Or also add [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for select only existed values from `group.index`:

```
return group.loc[selected.index.intersection(group.index, sort=False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jezrael said, use `loc` instead of `iloc`. I think you misunderstood label and position indexing (`loc` vs `iloc`) because often [index label](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label) is the same as [index position](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position) (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc). However, if your index contains names, your code doesn't work. Suppose the following minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2023)
group = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 9, (10, 6)))
group = group.add_prefix('row', axis=0).add_prefix('col', axis=1)
a, b = 2, 4
lowerInterval, upperInterval = 2, 5
print(group)

# Output
      col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
row0     8     2     7     8     2     5
row1     4     5     5     7     6     1
row2     7     2     8     6     8     6
row3     8     6     1     3     4     3
row4     5     2     7     1     8     8
row5     2     1     3     4     1     6
row6     2     1     2     3     4     2
row7     1     2     6     7     5     7
row8     8     8     8     1     1     8
row9     5     2     8     7     6     8
```

Now your code:

```
>>> cols = group.iloc[:, a:b+1]
      col2  col3  col4
row0     7     8     2
row1     5     7     6
row2     8     6     8
row3     1     3     4
row4     7     1     8
row5     3     4     1
row6     2     3     4
row7     6     7     5
row8     8     1     1
row9     8     7     6
```

```
#>>> sums = pd.DataFrame(cols.sum(axis=1))
>>> sums = cols.sum(axis=1).squeeze()  # A Series instead of a DataFrame
row0    17
row1    18
row2    22
row3     8
row4    16
row5     8
row6     9
row7    18
row8    10
row9    21
dtype: int64
```

```
#>>> selected = sums.loc[(sums.iloc[:,0]/(b-a+1) >= lowerInterval) & (sums.iloc[:,0]/(b-a+1) <= upperInterval)]
>>> selected = [sums.div(b-a+1).between(lowerInterval, upperInterval)]
row3     8
row5     8
row6     9
row8    10
dtype: int64
```

As you see, the index of `selected` contains labels not index position so you can't use `iloc`:

```
>>> group.iloc[selected.index.values]
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'row3'
```

Now the error is explicit, `iloc` expects integer values (position of the selected rows). You have to use `loc`:

```
>>> group.loc[selected.index]
      col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
row3     8     6     1     3     4     3
row5     2     1     3     4     1     6
row6     2     1     2     3     4     2
row8     8     8     8     1     1     8
```

To use `iloc`, you have to get the integer location with [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
>>> group.iloc[[group.index.get_loc(label) for label in selected.index]]
      col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
row3     8     6     1     3     4     3
row5     2     1     3     4     1     6
row6     2     1     2     3     4     2
row8     8     8     8     1     1     8
```

---

An example about your error:

```
sr = pd.Series(range(10, 20), index=range(1, 11))
print(sr)

# Output
1     10
2     11
3     12
4     13
5     14
6     15
7     16
8     17
9     18
10    19  # the 10th element so the position is 9 and the label is 10
dtype: int64
```

```
# With loc
>>> sr.loc[10]
19

# With iloc
>>> sr.iloc[10]
...
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

>>> sr.iloc[9]
19
```

Comment: Thank you for your explication, this is interesting. I didn't change indexes of the dataframe in any way, it is read from csv file, but I will keep this in mind.